# Passing int between two activities

Tags: java, android, variables, integer

I'm trying to pass `int` value between two activities. In first activity, I code :

```
Class nextView = Class.forName("com.test.NextFile");                    
Intent nextIntentTest = new Intent(CurrentFile.this, NextFile.class);
nextIntentTest.putExtra("passingName",nameofvar);
startActivity(nextIntentTest);
```

And, In second activity,

```
Intent intentTest = this.getIntent();
int counter = intentTest.getIntExtra("passingName",-1);
```

I don't know why, but I always get the default (-1) value. I've done almost the same thing with other classes and variables and everything was Okay. Maybe a problem is in `public class NextFile extends ListActivity` instead of `public class NextFile extends Avtivity` ?

Can someone help me ?

Comment: are you sure nameofvar is not -1 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm checking value of this variable in the CurrentFile and it isn't equal to -1.

Comment: Log your var before passing as extra to see it value

Comment: stupid question, but always good to ask : nameofvar is an int ?

Comment: where in your second activity do you get the int ? (good answer is in the onCreate or later, bad answer is in the constructor)

Comment: A bit weird! I imagine that the only possible answer is that 'nameofvar' is not an int. Maybe an array of ints? Could you show more code? By the way, why do you declare nextView and don't use it?

Comment: not an answer! post it as comment

Comment: It is an answer. As a say, the only possible answer I can imagine.

Comment: thiagolr answered more or less the same two minutes after me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    Bundle c = new Bundle();

    c.putInt("passingName",nameofvar);
     yourintent.putExtras(c);
```

to post the value

and

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int counter = b.getInt("passingName");  to retrieve it
```

Comment: Method putInt() doesn't exist. I think the only way to pass the value is to use putExtra();

Comment: in Intent.java we have `public Intent putExtra(String name, int value) {
 if (mExtras == null) {
  mExtras = new Bundle();
 }
 mExtras.putInt(name, value);
 return this;
}` this answer makes no sens, problem is somewhere else

Comment: Actually he just solved his problem and marked the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if "nameofvar" is not an int, try this:

```
Intent nextIntentTest = new Intent(CurrentFile.this, NextFile.class);
int newNameOfVar = 2;
nextIntentTest.putExtra("passingName",newNameOfVar);
startActivity(nextIntentTest);
```

On your second activity:

```
Intent intentTest = this.getIntent();
int counter = intentTest.getIntExtra("passingName",-1);
```

You can also print all the extras to see the value arriving:

```
Log.d("test", "extras = " + this.getIntent().getExtras());
```

Comment: `NEWnameofvar` should be `newNameOfVar`.